# How to repeatedly merge groups of files from the same folder?

Tags: r, loops, merge, repeat

I have 1 folder containing over 1000 files (title format = 5555_45). The first 4 digits always contain an identification code of files which belong together and should be merged. I would thus need to merge groups of files containing the same code and save it in another folder.

The code below allows me to merge ALL files within a folder and save it, and include the first four digits as a variable.

```
files <- list.files("PATH", pattern="*.TXT")
file.list <- lapply(files, read.table)
setattr(file.list, "names", files)
masterfilesales <- rbindlist(file.list, idcol="id")[, id := substr(id,1,4)]
write.table(masterfilesales, "PATH/5555.txt", sep="\t")
```

Is it possible to adjust this code (it works when I want to merge all files within a folder already) to do so repeatedly for files containing the same first 4 digits in my folder?

Comment: It looks like what you're doing is stacking data frames, rather than merging them.

Comment: And I think if you search on `[r] do.call rbind read.csv list.files` you will find several duplicates. This is isomorphic to a problem posed as homework in one of the Coursera R courses.

Answer (score 0):

The code below reads in the data using `sapply` instead of `lapply` because `sapply` automatically uses the file names as the names of each list element. Then we `rbind` each group of files that has the same four-digit prefix. Finally, we write each of the new stacked data frames using the four-digit prefix as the file name. You can do all this in one step, but I've separated them in the hope that the code will be easier to understand.

```
# Use sapply so that name of each list element will be the file name
file.list = sapply(files, read.table, simplify=FALSE)

# rbind each group of data frames that have the same four-digit prefix
file.list.stacked = sapply(unique(substr(names(file.list), 1, 4)), function(x) {
  do.call(rbind, file.list[grep(x, names(file.list))])
}, simplify=FALSE)

# Write the each of the new "stacked" data frames that we've just created
lapply(names(file.list.stacked), function(df) {
  write.table(file.list.stacked[[df]], file=paste0(df, ".txt"), sep="\t")
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly if I limit the size of the files within that folder, but it gets stuck given that i have around 200GB of data (an individual file would not be more than 15GB which should be fine on the server that I am running it on). Is there a way around the large file list you create?